# Смысл предложения

Tags: смысл

Здравствуйте. каков смысл предложения-"От оплаты взноса освобождаются команды состоящие из спортсменов до 1998 года рождения включительно."? спортсмены старше или младше 1998 года рождения?

Answer (score 11):

Спортсмены 1998 года рождения и ранее: 1997,1996,1995 и т.д.